# mySql how to order selected results by column value

Tags: mysql

I have a database Table.

In this table i have column name User_Id.

I want to order the results by 3 levels:

1. The first results should be specific user's id
   2+3. order by some columns.

is it possible to make some kind of query like this:

```
Select * From User
Order By User_Id = 1223, Start_Date, Last_Name;
```

**UPDATE:**

This is my Query:

```
SELECT Events.Event_Id, Events.Name as Event_Name, Events.Place, Events.Start_Time, Events.End_Time, getEventInvitedUsers(Events.Event_Id) as Invited_Users, getEventAttendingUsers(Events.Event_Id) as Attending_Users,
    Users.Facebook_Id, Users.Name as User_Name, Users_In_Events.Is_Attending as Is_Attending
FROM Users_In_Events 
Left Join Events
On Users_In_Events.Event_Id = Events.Event_Id
Left Join Users
On Events.Facebook_Id = Users.Facebook_Id
WHERE 
    Users_In_Events.Facebook_Id = 613714903         
    And 
    (Events.Start_Time > now()
    Or
    (Events.Start_Time > now() And Events.End_Time < now()))
    Order By Events.Facebook_Id= 613714903, Users_In_Events.Is_Attending, Events.Start_Time;
```

The query return all sort of Events from Events Table.

I wanted to know if its is possible to sort the results as i wrote in code above `Events.Facebook_Id= 613714903`

Comment: Could you reformulate your question or give and example of the order desired?

Comment: There is a way, but your SQL is not it.  Show sample output and explain how it should be sorted.

Comment: yes... it is possible but u cann't use = operator with order by cause.. so try this Select * From User
where User_Id = 1223
Order By User_Id, Start_Date, Last_Name;

Answer (score 0):

The best I can guess what you're asking for is this:

```
Select * From User
where User_Id = 1223
Order By User_Id, Start_Date, Last_Name;
```

This should fetch records where the `user_id` is 1223, and order them first by User_Id (why? they will all be 1223, so no sorting requried), then date, and last name.

But, to be honest, your question doesn't seem to make sense... in a `User` table, there's usually only one record per `user_id`, so there shouldn't be multiple rows to sort...